# Proguard: What rule can I add to avoid can’t find referenced class?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a function like this:

```
private fun enableSearch() {
        parentActivity?.let { parentActivity ->
            parentActivity.searchParamsObs
                    //This is for the first time, to avoid having an empty trolley
                    .flatMap { searchParams ->
                        Observable.combineLatest(searchService.search(searchParams).toObservable(), orderItemsService.getCachedTrolleyOrRequest(),
                                BiFunction<SearchResults, TrolleyItemsResponse, SearchListResultsAndTrolley> { searchResults, trolleyItems ->
                                    SearchListResultsAndTrolley(searchResults, trolleyItems)
                                })
                    }
                    .subscribeIO()
                    .observeMain()
                    .subscribe(
                            { updateScreenWithSearch(it) },
                            { e -> onSearchError(e) })
                    .addTo(disposables)

            parentActivity.focusSearchView()
        }

    }
```

Everytime I try to make a build with proguard enabled:

- com.my.package.features.search.fragments.ProductListFragment$enableSearch$1$1$1: can’t find referenced class
- com.my.package.features.search.fragments.ProductListFragment$enableSearch$1$1

I've pinpointed the problem to be the flatMap.. but I don't understand why.

Currently I have on proguard the following proguard config:

```
##########
# Android
##########

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }

##########
# View - Gets and setters - keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
##########

-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

##########
# Kotlin
##########
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-dontnote kotlin.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}

#Ignore null checks at runtime
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}

##########
# RxJava
##########

-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be caused by parentActivity?.let... don't understand why.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

include in gradle

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

$kotlin_version='1.1.51'